# What should I do when Fargate runs out of capacity?

Tags: amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I'm kicking off a single ECS Fargate task with a command such as:

```
aws ecs run-task --cluster Fargate \
 --task-definition $ECR_REPO-run-setup 
 --overrides file:///tmp/ecs-overrides-db-migrate.txt \
 --count 1 --launch-type FARGATE \
 --network-configuration "awsvpcConfiguration={subnets=[$PUBLIC_SUBNET_1, $PUBLIC_SUBNET_2],securityGroups=[$FARGATE_SG],assignPubli cIp=ENABLED}"
```

There are no ECS services, tasks or instances at all running in my account at the moment.  This is the response I get back:

```
{
    "failures": [
        {
            "reason": "Capacity is unavailable at this time. Please try again later or in a different availability zone"
        }
    ],
    "tasks": []
}
```

I don't even see a way to specify a different availability zone for a Fargate Task?

If I should just retry, how long should I wait before retries?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Withing a VPC you can create one or more subnets that correspond to an availability zone.

When launching your Fargate task you will notice the `network-configuration` parameter and associated `awsvpcConfiguration`. To specify multiple zones you can pass in multiple subnets. For example:

```
aws ecs run-task --cluster Fargate \
 --task-definition $ECR_REPO-run-setup 
 --overrides file:///tmp/ecs-overrides-db-migrate.txt \
 --count 1 --launch-type FARGATE \
 --network-configuration "awsvpcConfiguration={subnets=[$MY_SUBNET_IN_AZ1, 
$MY_SUBNET_IN_AZ2]
```

The VPC documentation in aws contains more helpful information:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_Subnets.html#vpc-subnet-basics

Comment: We're already putting in 2 subnets for 2 AZs.  Do you think we'd have a better chance of getting Capacity if we had all 4 AZs setup?

Comment: Ryan, curious -- did you eventually fix this? Do you know what you did?

Comment: Hey @ESRogs check this: https://www.theverge.com/2020/11/25/21719396/amazon-web-services-aws-outage-down-internet

Comment: Well, today AWS is having a huge outage: https://www.theverge.com/2020/11/25/21719396/amazon-web-services-aws-outage-down-internet

But at the time, there weren't enough spot instance machines available to fulfill my request. Adding multiple subnets fixed it for me.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this error running ECS tasks from a StepFunctions that already specified three different subnets in three different AZs (us-east-1{a,b,c}).

Because the ECS docs suggest retrying this error [1], I'm treating this as transient and retrying the error with a [StepFunction retry](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/concepts-error-handling.html) like below:

```
{

  "States": {

    "Workflow-EcsRunTask-EcsRunTask": {
      "End": true,
      "Retry": [
        {
          "ErrorEquals": [
            "ECS.AmazonECSException" // <-- this is the ECS error type thrown to StepFunction in case of this error
          ],
          "IntervalSeconds": 10,
          "MaxAttempts": 3,
          "BackoffRate": 2
        }
      ],
      "Type": "Task",
      "TimeoutSeconds": 43200,
      "HeartbeatSeconds": 300,
      "Resource": "arn:<REDACTED>"
      ... 

    }

  }

}
```

[1]:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/userguide/service-event-messages.html : see *service (service-name) was unable to place a task. Reason: Capacity is unavailable at this time. Please try again later or in a different availability zone.*

> You can do one the following:
>
> - Wait until the Fargate capacity or EC2 container instances become available.
> - Relaunch the service and specify additional subnets.